# How to use the AWS SDK from an OSGi bundle in AEM 6.5 maven project

Tags: amazon-web-services, aem, opensearch

How to integrate AWS software packages, dependencies and integrate with AWS console options from an aem project. Is it possible to integrate with open search from an osgi bundle to use in AEM?

Need to resolve org.software.aws dependencies inside osgi bundle. But aem tries to download from adobe public repo. Any leads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the AWS SDK to an AEM OSGi bundle. The trick is you have to configure the OSGi bundle to use  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk. This is where the  AWS Java SDK V2 dependencies are located. Once you do that -- you can successfully build the OSGi to include the AWS SDK Java API.

Comment: Thanks @smac2020 initially I give a try with this for making the bundle active